# Need help in setting up Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I need some help in setting up Hibernate. I have installed eclipse and mysql and written a simple program to store a table in the db. But I am getting the below exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
at org.hibernate.exception.ErrorCodeConverter.handledNonSpecificException(ErrorCodeConverter.java:92)
```

Basically I have created a database called Contact and inside that a table called Contact in MySQL. My configuration file is as below

```
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/contact</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">anandi</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">anandi</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

Is the above ok ? The user and password are correct but I have some doubts about the property name="hibernate.connection.url parameter. Can anyone help as to why I am getting the exception and what should be the fix for the same. I have spent a while on this and so any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
    Dev

Comment: Is your DB running on localhost, and has a contact schema?

Comment: Yes I have installed mysql in my local machine. I have created a database named contact and I have also created a table called contact in this database. Any help on what is missing?

Comment: Basically I have installed mysql in the following path - C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1 and the database is physically stored in C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\data\contact. Should I give the complete path in the connection.url ?

Comment: Hello ...can anyone help me in this . I would be very grateful if anyone can help as I need to get hibernate working.

Comment: Can you post more of the exception trace, specifically a Caused by line?

Answer (score 3):

In your url property you have to give at the end your database name. In your case it's Contact (not contact). 
jdbc:mysql://localhost/Contact
The database name is case sensitive in Mysql.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using standard MySQL installation specify port number in connection:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Contact
```

Comment: Port number is not required if the mysql server is running on default port 3306